# Number of permutations of the sequence

Tags: combinatorics

How can I find the number of permutations without repetitions of the sequence of all natural numbers from $1$ to $n$ such that every permutation starts with $1$ and ends with $n$ and the difference between any consecutive terms of permutation is no greater than $3$, i.e. $\lvert a_{i+1} - a_{i}\rvert\in\{1,2,3\}$?

Thanks!

Comment: This is [A174700](http://oeis.org/A174700) in Sloane's.  It doesn't look like there's any nice formula or generating function.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Nice reference - however the OP imposed another condition, namely that the sequence starts with a $1$ which affects the figures in a non-trivial way ...

Comment: The list of figures given the additional condition that the sequence should start with a $1$ begins like this: 

1, 1, 2, 6, 18, 42, 90, 197, 442, 984, 2152, 4660, 10064, 21700, 46656, 99999, ...

Comment: @String: Ah, you are right.  I read too quickly.

Comment: I forgot one more condition: permutation must end with n. I've edited the question.

Comment: @String : Maybe if you have already programmed something it could be altered to include this last condition (last term is n), and it then might be at o.e.i.s. (I could see why you might not want to do this...) The sequence of your last comment wasn't at o.e.i.s.

Comment: The number of such permutations is sequence 1,1,1,2,6,14,28,56,118,254,541 and there is no record in OEIS for it. Even Wolfram's Mathematica is not able to find the recurrence with FindLinearRecurrence...

Comment: Yes, given the last condition of ending with $n$ the first 20 figures read: 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 14, 28, 56, 118, 254, 541, 1140, 2401, 5074, 10738, 22711, 48001, 101447. Thank you, @coffeemath. I wonder if a closed form would be possible, but perhaps the assumptions are too involved for that ...?

Comment: @String A closed form would be odd since it eludes OEIS (But not impossible, many sequences not there...) Anyway thanks for doing the new calculation (agrees with user144765's comment above)! It'll give something to check back on if any tentative patterns seem to emerge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was fairly tough and my solution is complicated.

The problem is equivalent to finding the number of ways to jump from square $0$ to square $n$ on a row of squares, without jumping further than three spaces at a time, and without missing any squares in between.

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\blacksquare&\square&\square&\square&\ldots&\square\\
0&1&2&3&&n\end{array}$$

If you experiment a little with the problem, you will find that if you are not allowed to move more than two spaces at a time, then your progress from left to right is highly predictable. However, when you can move three spaces at a time, it is possible to make a sequence of long jumps to the right, double back *once*, and then return, having filled in all the squares you missed. The fact that the ways to do so are limited makes the problem tractable.

First, we start with an empty row, and shade the first square. We can then draw a vertical line after the first square, to remind us that all the squares to the left of the line have been filled. Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to get to square n, obeying the rules.

Now, there are three possibilities: jump one square, jump two squares, or jump three squares.

In the first case:

$$\begin{array}{|ccccc}\blacksquare&\square&\square&\square&\ldots\end{array}$$

we could draw a new vertical line after the square just shaded, and we'd be in the exact same situation again, but with one square fewer. So from this point on, there are $f(n-1)$ ways to get to square $n$.

In the second case, we have the following situation:

$$\begin{array}{|ccccc}\square&\blacksquare&\square&\square&\ldots\end{array}$$

Let $g(n)$ be the number of ways to get to the last square from this configuration.

In the third case, we have:

$$\begin{array}{|cccccc}\square&\square&\blacksquare&\square&\square&\ldots\end{array}$$

Let $h(n)$ be the number of ways to get to the last square from this configuration.

The easy part is to see that $f(n)=f(n-1)+g(n-1)+h(n-1)$. After that it gets tricky.

In the second case, call the shaded square "1"; then the next moves can be 1-0-2 or 1-0-3 or 1-2-0-3 or 1-3-0-2-4 or 1-3-0-2-5, or 1-4... (long leaps to the right)

In the third case, call the shaded square "2"; then the next moves can be 2-0-1-3 or 2-0-1-4 or 2-1-0-3 (but only if all squares to the left of the line are filled) or 2-0-3-1-4 or 2-3-0-1-4 or 2-4-1-0-3-5 or 2-4-1-0-3-6, or 2-5... (long leaps to the right)

How can we deal with multiple leaps to the right? Actually, it's quite simple: let $\hat{h}(n)$ be the number of ways to get to square $n$ in the third case, if squares remain to be filled on the left of the vertical line. It turns out that the order in which those earlier squares get filled is entirely dependent on what happens to the right of the line.

Putting it all together:

$\begin{array}{rcl}f(n)&=&f(n-1)+g(n-1)+h(n-1)\\
g(n)&=&f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-4)+g(n-2)+g(n-4)+\hat{h}(n-2)\\
h(n)&=&2f(n-3)+2f(n-4)+f(n-5)+g(n-3)+g(n-5)+\hat{h}(n-3)\\
\hat{h}(n)&=&h(n)-f(n-4)
\end{array}$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&\ldots\\
\hline f&1&1&1&2&6&14&28&56&\ldots\\
g&0&0&1&2&4&8&17&37&\ldots\\
h&0&0&0&2&4&6&11&25&\ldots\\
\hat{h}&0&0&0&2&3&5&10&23&\ldots
\end{array}$$

It is easy to continue this table using a computer. For example I found that, for one hundred squares, the answer is $f(99)=46103635399805799327514181735963$. I will add this sequence to the OEIS if you like.

**Edit:** I've found a simpler way to express the recurrence:
$$f(n)=1\cdot f(n-1)+0\cdot f(n-2)+1\cdot f(n-3)+3\cdot f(n-4)+...$$
The coefficients start $1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10,$ and from that point each new coefficient is the sum of the last and the third-last, so $5+10=15,$ then $7+15=22,$ etc.

Comment: Oh very nice! I tried doing this at first but got stuck on the $\hat{h}(n)$ case.

Comment: Do you have a combinatorial explanation for the simpler expression or did you just expand the $g,h,\hat{h}$ recurrences?

Comment: Your sequence satisfies the recurrence relation $f(n) = 2f(n-1) - f(n-2) + 2f(n-3) + f(n-4) + f(n-5) - f(n-7) - f(n-8)$ with initial values $f(0),\ldots,f(7) = 1,1,1,2,6,14,28,56$. Therefore $f(n) = \Theta(\alpha^n)$, where $\alpha \approx 2.11393$ is the maximal real root of $x^8-2x^7+x^6-2x^5-x^4-x^3+x+1$.

Comment: Nice @YuvalFilmus I found a slightly different expression for the characteristic polynomial, leading to the recurrence $$ f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} + f_{n-3} + 3f_{n-4} + 2f_{n-5} + f_{n-6} - f_{n-7} - 2f_{n-8} - f_{n-9}$$

Comment: My recurrence is minimal. The sequence doesn't satisfy any shorter linear relation.

Comment: Nice approach! +1

Answer (score 8):

**See the second part for a discussion of Andrew's solution**

This problem is equivalent to counting the number of Hamiltonian paths in the generalization of the following graph (n=8)

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad$ [image]

Of course, this doesn't necessarily mean that the problem is NP-hard, since these graphs are "nice" (symmetric, degree<7, etc). Using the typical dynamic programming algorithm which counts by ({nodes visited}, current node) I managed to count the permutations for $n\le30$.

$$
\begin{array} (
 & \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\
 14 & 28 & 56 & 118 & 254 \\
 541 & 1140 & 2401 & 5074 & 10738 \\
 22711 & 48001 & 101447 & 214446 & 453355 \\ 
 958395 & 2025963 & 4282685 & 9053286 & 19138115 \\
 40456779 &  85522862  &  180789396 &  382176531 &  807895636 \\ & \\ & \\
\end{array}
$$

---

$$ \qquad $$

Andrew Woods posted a very nice solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179077/202838). I just want to add a few things. First note his offset for the sequence (my $a_n$ equals his $f_{n-1}$). Because we have a linear recurrence, we can use the matrix-[exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method to calculate the value $a_n$ for very large values of $n$. For example, 
$$
\begin{array} (
a_{100} &= 46103635399805799327514181735963 \qquad \checkmark \\
a_{10^{10000}} &= 75922134066658345530 \; \left(\,\text{mod } 10^{20}\,\right)
\end{array}
$$

The recurrence matrix $M$ and initial vector $b$ are

$$
\tiny
M = \left(
\begin{array} (
. & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & 1 & 1 & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . \\
. & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & . & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 \\
-1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad
b = \left(
\begin{array} (
f_0 \\ f_1 \\ f_2 \\ f_3 \\ f_4 \\
g_0 \\ g_1 \\ g_2 \\ g_3 \\ g_4 \\ h_4 \\ \hat{h}_2 \\ \hat{h}_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array} (
1\\1\\1\\2\\6\\0\\0\\1\\2\\4\\4\\0\\2\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

where the omitted values are all zeros. Then $a_n$ is simply the first coordinate of $M^{n-1} b$. The next step is to find the characteristic equation of $M$.

---

You can find the characteristic equation of $M$ using Matlab's $\texttt{charpoly}$ command, which yields $x^{13} - x^{12} - x^{11} - x^{10} - 3x^9 - 2x^8 - x^7 + x^6 + 2x^5 + x^4 $, giving us the recurrence
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + 3a_{n-4} + 2a_{n-5} + a_{n-6} -a_{n-7} - 2a_{n-8} -a_{n-9} $$

Yuval Filmus calculated the characteristic equation using a different method, yielding the minimal linear recurrence

$$ a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3} + a_{n-4} + a_{n-5} - a_{n-7} - a_{n-8} $$

Note that if you subtract the second recurrence from the first, you get the second recurrence shifted by one (the term corresponding to the root (-1) vanishes). To be complete, another interesting recurrence that Andrew found is

$$ 
\begin{array} (
a_n &= a_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + 3a_{n-4} + 4a_{n-5} + 5a_{n-6} + 7a_{n-7} + 10a_{n-8} + ... \\
&:= \sum_{i\ge1}{c_i a_{n-i}}
\end{array}
$$

where the coefficient $c_i = c_{i-1} + c_{i-3}$ for $i>8$. I presume that he found this recurrence by expanding the recurrences $g,h,\hat{h}$ from his post (that's how I found it). Finally, as Yuval noted, we get a growth rate $a_n = \Theta(\gamma^n)$ where $\gamma \approx 2.11393$ is the magnitude of the largest root of the characteristic equation.

Comment: You can find the characteristic equation, which happens to have degree $8$, in my comment to Andrew's answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus how did you calculate the characteristic equation? I used Matlab to get a ninth order equation -- how did you reduce it to eighth order?

Comment: I calculated many terms of the sequence, then computed a matrix with $n$ rows of length $m$, each containing $m$ consecutive elements of the sequence. I then computed the kernel. If it's not empty for "large" $n$ and the appropriate $m$, there is a linear relation. If it is empty (i.e. contains only the zero vector), them $m$ is too small.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Good team-work! +1 for all of You! :-)

Comment: Can you tell which tool to use for fast matrix exponentiation? Or provide code snippet? Now I have linear recurrence of 120th order and it is needed to compute 10^14th term. I'm stuck with Python implementation...

Comment: @user144765 Here is some Python [code](https://github.com/Turing-Apparatus/Stack_Exchange---Reddit/blob/master/Local/mat_bin_exp.py) for matrix exponentiation. Where are you getting a 120th order recurrence / what is it? I have code that will reduce it if possible (similar to what Yuval did).

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think it is possible to reduce it because of its recurrence was produced from minimal characteristic polynomial. Here is naive Python implementation for it: http://pastebin.com/c4XC2EqK. In fact, it is a recurrence for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^3$, where $a_{i}$ is recurrence which I asked for in question. If you could help me to compute it for $n = 10^{14}$ by $mod 10^9$ it would be priceless.

Comment: @Andrew: I have managed to compute it by myself with your code. I was stuck with transposition matrix but now it is clear for me how to derive it. Thank you for all your help! You are awesome!

Comment: @user144765 you're welcome! How did you come up with the 120th order recurrence for $\sum a_i^3$?

Comment: @Andrew: I generated a bunch of values of $\sum a_{i}^3$ using naive recursion with memoization and then used [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)'s realization of Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to derive minimal characteristic polynomial for that sequence. It appeared that only 242 initial values was required to produce MCp. Luckily, linear recurrence satisfying that MCP was able to produce correct values up to 10^14.

Comment: Ah okay. I implemented BM in python and it takes ~20 minutes to compute. Thought there would be a better way. It's easy to see that it will be 120th order, btw. There are 8 simple roots of the characteristic equation. Meaning $a_n = \gamma_1 r_1^n + \ldots + \gamma_8 r_8^n$. So $ \sum a_i^3 = \beta_1 q_1^n + \ldots + \beta_m q_m^n$ where $q_k = (r_a r_b r_c)$ are the distinct 3-combinations of the roots. The number of such combinations is easily counted to be $m=120$.

Comment: @user144765 Actually, $m=121$ because of the root $q_{121} = 1$. If $f_n = \sum g_i^k$ and $g_n$ is of order $h$, then the order of $f_n$ is bounded by ${h+k-1 \choose k} + k-1$. For $h,k = 8,3$ we get a bound of 122.

Comment: @andrew: wow, that's great! Thanks for the explanations! I need to learn more about linear recurrences.

Comment: @AndrewSzymczak: Sorry, but can I ask for your help one more time - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192590/sequences-of-sums-of-pascals-triangle?