# Sequences of sums of Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The sequence
$$
1,3,6,10,16,28,56,120,256,528,1056
$$
is defined in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A038505) as "sum of every 4th entry of row n in Pascal's triangle, starting at "n choose 2"". It satisfies the recurrence 
$$
a(n) = 4a(n-1)-6a(n-2)+4a(n-3)
$$
and can be explicitly calculated as 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}{n+1 \choose 2k}\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}
$$

I suspect that following sequences 
$$
0,0,3,21,89,307,977,3031,9321,28479,86505,261615,788969,2375119
$$
$$
1,7,31,117,439,1729,7063,29201,120471,493617,2008567,8129265
$$
$$
0,0,10,122,906,5478,30274,160974,840602,4343142,22270674
$$
also relate to sums of terms in Pascal's triangle but can't figure it out.
For example, the first of above-mentioned sequences has minimal characteristic polynomial 
$$
x^6 - 8x^5 + 27x^4 - 54x^3 + 70x^2 - 56x + 24
$$

Can any relation with Pascal's triangle can be established for that sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do the three sequences come from? (How are you calculating them)

Comment: By definition, I think a more intuitive explicit formula is $a(n) = {n \choose 2} + {n \choose 6} + {n \choose 10} + \ldots = \sum_{k \ge 0} {n \choose 4k-2}$. Note the offset on the OEIS is wrong. With an offset 0 the sequence should start 0,0,1,3,...

Comment: See [Gosper's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper's_algorithm) and [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf-Zeilberger_pair).

Comment: @Lucian: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to relate a sequence to Pascal's triangle, it's usually a good idea to write out the sequence in the basis of binomial coefficients. We can do this by computing the difference table. Suppose we have a sequence $h_n$, then our difference table is computed

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad $ [image]

where $\Delta h_n = h_{n+1} - h_n$. In such a table, the 0th diagonal $h_0, \Delta h_0, \Delta^2 h_0, \ldots =: c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots$ gives us our sequence in terms of the binomial coefficients.

$$ h_n = c_0 {n \choose 0} + c_1 {n \choose 1} + c_2 {n \choose 2} + \ldots $$

Let's look at the difference table for your first sequence $g_n$

$$
\tiny
\begin{array} {cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\\
0 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 0 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 3 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 21 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 89 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 307 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 977 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 3031 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 9321 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 28479 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 86505 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 261615 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 788969   \\  
& 0 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 3 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 18 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 68 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 218 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 670 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 2054 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 6290 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 19158 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 58026 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 175110 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 527354   \\  
&& 3 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 15 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 50 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 150 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 452 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1384 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 4236 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 12868 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 38868 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 117084 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 352244   \\  
&&& 12 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 35 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 100 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 302 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 932 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 2852 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 8632 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 26000 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 78216 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 235160   \\  
&&&& 23 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 65 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 202 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 630 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1920 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 5780 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 17368 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 52216 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 156944   \\  
&&&&& 42 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 137 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 428 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1290 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 3860 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 11588 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 34848 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 104728   \\  
&&&&&& 95 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 291 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 862 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 2570 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 7728 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 23260 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 69880   \\  
&&&&&&& 196 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 571 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1708 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 5158 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 15532 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 46620   \\  
&&&&&&&& 375 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1137 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 3450 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 10374 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 31088   \\  
&&&&&&&&& 762 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 2313 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 6924 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 20714   \\  
&&&&&&&&&& 1551 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 4611 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 13790   \\  
&&&&&&&&&&& 3060 \!\!\!\!\!\!\! && \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 9179   \\  
&&&&&&&&&&&& 6119 & \ldots  \\ 
\end{array}
$$

The zeroth diagonal is $\boldsymbol{c} = [0, 0, 3, 12, 23, 42, 95, 196, 375, 762, 1551, 3060, 6119]$, meaning $g_n = 3 {n \choose 2} + 12 {n \choose 3} + \ldots$. It turns out that there is a linear dependence of the terms $c_k$

$$ c_k = 2c_{k-1} - 2c_{k-2} + 6c_{k-3} - 5c_{k-4} + 4c_{k-5} - 4c_{k-6} $$

So $g_n$ is the inner product of the linear recurrence $\boldsymbol{c}$ and the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle. I don't think we can do much better than that. Unfortunately, the other two sequences don't have enough terms to extrapolate any relation.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
The terms of the second recurrence are:
$$
0,0,3,21,89,307,977,3031,9321,28479,86505,261615,788969,2375119,7141769,21457999,64439145,193447887,580605705
$$
The third one:
$$
1,7,31,117,439,1729,7063,29201,120471,493617,2008567,8129265,32781847,131886705,529800951,2126056497,8525233303
$$
These terms are all I have for now: I generate them using bruteforce so it takes a lot of time.
I want to generalize these secuences, i.e. generate any following one.

Comment: @user144765 What are you brute-forcing? It would help to have some context.

Comment: @user144765 btw, you gave me the first ($g_n$) and second sequence not the second and third.

Comment: About the origin of these sequences - http://pastebin.com/KH2rRFNU

Comment: I meant the second and the third ones after the first which is in OEIS. All sequences start with offset one not zero.

Comment: @user144765 Let's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21994/chat-for-a-question)

Comment: For the second sequence (1,7,31,117,...) characteristic polynomial $x^9 - 14x^8 + 85x^7 - 304x^6 + 732x^5 - 1272x^4 + 1640x^3 - 1536x^2 + 992x - 384$. I still can't find any patterns.

Comment: @user144765 yea I don't know... if you get rid of the "even" restriction, then $$G(\bullet;H) = {W \choose 1} G(;H-1) - {W \choose 2} G(;H-2) + \ldots \\ G(W;\bullet) = (2H-1) G(W-1;) - 2{H \choose 2} G(W-2;) = H^W - G(W,H-1)$$ The second provides a nice characteristic polynomial that might help you. For example, you might be able to relate $$\begin{array}{ll} G_{\text{even}}(W;3) &= [8, -27, 54, -70, 56, -24]_{\text{rec}} \\ G_{\text{odd}}(W;3) &= [6, -15, 24, -22, 12]_{\text{rec}} \\ G(W;3) &= [5, -6]_{\text{rec}} = G_e(W,3) + G_o(W,3) =\ldots \end{array}$$

Comment: It seems I've overcomplicated things a lot, fascinated by matrix exponentiation. Wouldn't it be easier to derive explicit formula for $G_{even}(W,\bullet)$ knowing that it has characteristic polynomial $(x^2-1)^k$ instead of keeping it still recursive and trying to find explicit formula for $G_{even}(\bullet,H)$ to produce initial values for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment, let's continue the chat under this post so we can view equations). I was trying to do that in the chatroom, to no avail. And you still need the initial values. The characteristic polynomial uniquely specifies the recurrence, not the sequence. Btw, I think it's better to use the $\bullet$ for the index being held fixed. So $G_{e}(\bullet,H)$ is the sequence $G_e(W,1), G_e(W,2), \ldots$, and it has characteristic polynomial $(x^2-1)^W$. Thus, the general solution is of the form 
$$G_e(W,H) = \sum_{k=0}^{W-1} (\alpha_k + (-1)^H \beta_k) \, H^k
$$
So you need to find constants $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ that satisfy the initial conditions. To make this a little easier
we can decouple the sequence into two independent ones; let $G_{e}'$ denote every odd term of the sequence and $G_{e}''$ denote every even term. That is, $G_{e}'(\bullet,h) = G_{e}(\bullet,2h-1)$ and $G_e''(\bullet,h) = G_e(\bullet,2h)$. Then both $G_e'$ and $G_e''$ have characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^W$. This means that the general solution of each of these will be of the form

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{W-1} \alpha_k \, H^k $$

In chat I found the first few of these
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
G_e'(1,h) &= 0 \\
G_e''(1,h) &= 1 \\
G_e'(2,h) &= 0 \\
G_e''(2,h) &= 2h+1 \\
G_e'(3,h) &= 1 - 3h + 2h^2 \\
G_e''(3,h) &= 25 - 35h + 10h^2 \\
G_e'(4,h) &= -5 + (55/3)h - 24h^2 + 32h^3 \\
G_e''(4,h) &= -1 + (17/3)h - 16h^2 + (64/3)h^3 \\
\end{array}
$$
They don't seem to follow any sort of pattern. You might try to find a pattern in the full sequence $G_e$.

Comment: $$
G_{e}(2,n): \left\{\left\{a(n)\to \frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^n+1\right) (2 n-1)\right\}\right\}
$$
$$
G_{e}(3,n): \left\{\left\{a(n)\to \frac{1}{2} \left(2 (-1)^n n^2+3 n^2-2 (-1)^n n-3
   n+(-1)^n+1\right)\right\}\right\}
$$
$$
G_{e}(4,n): \left\{\left\{a(n)\to \frac{1}{12} \left(8 (-1)^n n^3+24 n^3-12 (-1)^n n^2-36
   n^2+10 (-1)^n n+24 n-3 (-1)^n-9\right)\right\}\right\}
$$
$$
G_{e}(5,n): \left\{\left\{a(n)\to \frac{1}{6} (n-1) \left(2 (-1)^n n^3+15 n^3-2 (-1)^n n^2-15
   n^2+2 (-1)^n n+15 n-6\right)\right\}\right\}
$$
Looks like coefficients in these explicit formulas are binomials...

Comment: @user144765 ah you beat me to the punch. Just to view the coefficients in a more succinct form $[\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots; \beta_0, \ldots]$ $$1/2 \; [1\;;\; 1] \\
1/2\; [-1, 2 \;;\; -1, 2] \\
1/2\;[1, -3, 3 \;;\; 1, -2, 2] \\
1/12\;[-9, 24, -36, 24 \;;\; -3, 10, -12, 8] \\
1/6\;[6, -21, 30, -30, 15 \;;\; 0, -2, 4, -4, 2] $$

Comment: It must relate to binomials. Looks very similar to the explicit formula in the question. That ${-1}^n$s remind me inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Hmm that's a good idea. I'll try to think of an IE or an involution. Though I do enjoy the lazy pattern searching method.

Comment: Any integer-valued polynomial is an integer linear combination of binomial coefficients. And
${x \choose 1} = x; {x \choose 2} = \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x; {x \choose 3} = \frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x; ...$
But that $(-1)^n$s...

Comment: I've found this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1206018/144765) to be promising enough. But the recurrence for $G_{e}(W, n)$ is sign-changing sum and I'm not proficient with such things.

Comment: @user144765 Hey did you ever end up solving this? Just realized it's an Euler problem so I started thinking about it again.