# Simplying linear recurrence sum with binomials

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to simplify

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}f(k)$$

Where $f(k)$ is a large linear recurrence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Assuming that $f(k)$ is a sequence with a characteristic polynomial $p(x)$, then:
$$ G(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\,f(k) $$
gives a linear recurrence, too, and the characteristic polynomial associated with $G(n)$ is just $p(x-1)$, by the binomial theorem. For instance, if $f(k)$ is the $k$-th Fibonacci number, we have $p(x)=x^2-x-1$ and:
$$ G(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}F_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\phi^n-\bar\phi^n\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left((1+\phi)^n-(1+\bar\phi)^n\right), $$
so:
$$ G(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^{2n}-\bar\phi^{2n}\right) = F_{2n} $$
is a sequence with characteristic polynomial $x^2-3x+1 = p(x-1)$.

Comment: @user226339: if you know the matrix then you know the characteristic polynomial of the sequence, that is the same as the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. It follows that the matrix associated with the sequence $F(n)$ is the original matrix plus the identity matrix.